# Migrate Spring cloud stream application - Chelsea to Horsham

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to migrate a Spring Cloud Stream application Chelsea.SR1 to Horsham. This project does not have binder but uses spring messaging and integration to integrate a custom source and sink.

It looks like `AggregateApplicationBuilder` is not available anymore. How do I bind the source, transformer and sink without `AggregateApplicationBuilder` ?

Or is there a better way to implement this in Horsham? The only constraint I have is, I need to use Pollable source/consumer.

Thanks in advance!

pom.xml

```
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>example-info-processor</artifactId>
  <groupId>com.example.streams</groupId>
  <version>1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
  </parent>
  <properties>
    <spring-cloud.version>Chelsea.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.17.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.15.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.20.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.24.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

Application

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "com.example.streams",
})
public class ExampleInfoProcessorApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AggregateApplicationBuilder(ExampleInfoProcessor.class, args)
                .from(ExampleInfoConsumer.class).via(ExampleInfoTransformer.class)
                .to(ExampleInfoSink.class).run(args);
    }
}
```

Source

```
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
public class ExampleInfoConsumer {
    @Autowired
    private MyConsumer customConsumer;

    @InboundChannelAdapter(value = Source.OUTPUT, poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "30"))
    public List<ExampleRecord> consume() {
      //Read the available chunk from the source location
            .....
        return exampleRecordsList;
    }
}
```

Transformer

```
@EnableBinding(Processor.class)
public class ExampleInfoTransformer {

    @Transformer(inputChannel = Processor.INPUT, outputChannel = Processor.OUTPUT)
    public Map<String, List<ExampleInfo>> transform(List<ExampleRecord> exampleRecords) {
        //transform the consumer records, store the list of ExampleInfo objects in a map using ExampleInfo key
        return map;
    }
}
```

Sink

```
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class ExampleInfoSink {

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = Sink.INPUT)
    public void sink(Map<String, List<ExampleInfo>>  exampleInfoMap) {
        //Read from map and write to destination.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using only spring-integration and spring-messaging why do you have spring-cloud-stream as a dependency instead of just spring-integration which is a top level framework? *How do I bind the source, transformer and sink without. . .* - Source has *output channel* and transformer has *input channel*. As long as output and input are the same channel your components are connected. But that has nothing to do with spring-cloud-stream. That is pure spring-integration.

Chelsea is a very old version (1.x). We've deprecated `AggregateApplicationBuilder` in 2.x and removed it in 3.x in favor of functional composition. 
We also no longer promote annotation-based configuration model for spring-cloud-stream in favor of function-based programming model.

Please read the following posts we published recently:

- https://spring.io/blog/2019/10/14/spring-cloud-stream-demystified-and-simplified
- https://spring.io/blog/2019/10/17/spring-cloud-stream-functional-and-reactive
- https://spring.io/blog/2019/10/25/spring-cloud-stream-and-spring-integration
- https://spring.io/blog/2019/10/31/spring-cloud-stream-event-routing